# Is it possible to forward declare a enum class to be used in a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, enumerator

I'm currently making a small little parser for this simple GUI scripting language that I'm creating. Everything works fine, but I need to know if it's possible to do this:

Parser.hpp:

```
class Parser
{
public:
    enum class LineType;
}
```

GUIParser.hpp:

```
class GUIParser : public Parser
{
public:
        enum class LineType
        {
            BACKGROUND,
            BUTTON,
            LABEL,
            RADIOBOX,
            COMMENT
        };
}
```

This gives me an error, but if it's possible then what syntactical error am I making?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Which compiler, which version, which operating system? Did you explicitly enable [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) e.g. `-std=c++11` with GCC 4.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's declaring that there's an enum called `LineType` inside `Parser` or:  `Parser::LineType` .

In the derived class you have  an enum called `LineType`, and its full 'name' will be: `GUIParser::LineType`.

So, because you can't predict the name of the derived class, you can't forward declare what it will contain.

That's the logic behind it, the simpler answer is: no, it's not in the standard.